# Can pods access frameworks in main project?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, podspec, react-native-bridge

there is an SDK developed for Native iOS. I'm trying to create a React Native bridge for this SDK. My goal is to be able to establish the bridge without breaking the native ios integration. Can I access the `.framework` extension SDK in the main project from within my bridge POD? is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. You cannot access an object that is not part of your framework.

In best practice, a **child** class should not know anything about a **parent** class.

You may define `default` values for that framework's properties or you may create an other shared library.

You may find a similar case on this topic: [Access parent class from subproject framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008777/access-parent-class-from-subproject-framework)